# linker command failed "ld: library not found for -lOpenNI" in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, kinect, ld, openni

I'm trying to use OpenNI with my kinect but I have a problem during the build. I get this error :

```
ld: library not found for -lOpenNI
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I try "ld -lOpenNI" in terminal it finds it, and the path to the libOpenNI.dylib has been added to the library search paths (it's just /usr/lib). It has also been linked in "link binary With Libraries". I have tried to clean the build folder.

The whole compiler argument is :

```
Ld /Users/henrax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/handtracker-dafbaeqppvdfnfhgffkyffwhskyl/Build/Products/Debug/handtracker normal x86_64
cd /Users/henrax/Documents/handtracker
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.11
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -L/Users/henrax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/handtracker-dafbaeqppvdfnfhgffkyffwhskyl/Build/Products/Debug -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib -F/Users/henrax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/handtracker-dafbaeqppvdfnfhgffkyffwhskyl/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/henrax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/handtracker-dafbaeqppvdfnfhgffkyffwhskyl/Build/Intermediates/handtracker.build/Debug/handtracker.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/handtracker.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -stdlib=libc++ -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL /Applications/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-MacOSX-v1.5.7.10/Samples/NiHandTracker/x64-Release/NiHandTracker.o /Applications/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-MacOSX-v1.5.7.10/Samples/NiHandTracker/x64-Release/NiHandViewer.o /Applications/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-MacOSX-v1.5.7.10/Samples/NiHandTracker/x64-Release/NiSimpleViewer.o -lOpenNI -lOpenNI.jni /Applications/Kinect/OpenNI-Bin-Dev-MacOSX-v1.5.7.10/Samples/NiHandTracker/x64-Release/main.o -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/henrax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/handtracker-dafbaeqppvdfnfhgffkyffwhskyl/Build/Intermediates/handtracker.build/Debug/handtracker.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/handtracker_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/henrax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/handtracker-dafbaeqppvdfnfhgffkyffwhskyl/Build/Products/Debug/handtracker
```

It seems like a pretty easy problem but I have searched and not found any solution. Any help would be very welcomed !